# How do I reduce compile times for constexpr functions?

Tags: c++, optimization, constexpr

Suppose we want to build a non-trivial table at compile time

```
template<int N, int M>
constexpr auto foo()
{
    std::array<std::array<int, N>, M> a = {};
    for(int m = 1; m < M; m++)
        for(int n = 1; n < N; n++)
        {
            // For exposition only
            auto x = (m ^ 42) + (n << 3) - m;
            auto y = (n ^ 420) + (m % 420);
            a[m][n] = (a[(x + m) % m][(y + n) % n] + (x ^ y)) % 0xFACADE;
        }
    return a;
}

constexpr auto bar(int n, int m)
{
    constexpr auto dim = /* something */;
    constexpr auto table = foo<dim, dim>();
    return table[n][m];
}
```

[It doesn't take much](https://godbolt.org/z/cxryby) to push compile times over the top. The alternative is to generate the table as source code via a script, which is obviously much less nice.

How do I reduce the compile times such functions?

---

### Some motivation

`constexpr` functions differ hugely from regular functions, evident by the extreme slowness compared to regular functions. Aside from being executed by the compiler, they have bounds checking, overflow checking and pretty much all UB preventing checks in place. I suspect this renders most intuition gathered from regular functions useless.

Comment: Does it *have* to be done at compile-time? What is the real problem you try to solve with this? What is the use-case?

Comment: Run it locally. There is no *top* *(or timeout) on your local machine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No. But the original problem piqued my interest. On another note, I can think of a certain constexpr parser I've once attempted wanting to build stuff at compile time. This is certainly a problem for folly/Format.

Comment: @Codo I meant it makes compile times ridiculously long.

Comment: I wonder if precompiled headers could be useful here?  (they wouldn't reduce the compile-time directly, but they could reduce the number of times you have to recompile the code by caching the results of the first compile for re-use)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I'm guessing yes and no. Yes if it's the exact same function, but no if it has different template parameters.

Comment: Agreed -- but if you're generating it at compile-time, then it's usually the case that the parameters will be the same on each compile (they'd only be different if you modified them in the source code, which is hopefully a rare event).  The benefits should be the same as generating the table as source code via a script (as the questioner suggested), except that instead of generating source code, the compiler is generating object-code (and there's no need to write a script)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the compiler just optimize the following points, so probably you get no advantages, but:

1) `m ^ 42` and `m % 420` doesn't depends from `n`, so you can compute they outside the inner loop

2) if I'm not wrong,

```
(x + m) % m  ==  x % m + m % m
             ==  x % m + 0
             ==  x % m
```

and

```
(y + n) % n  ==  y % n + n % n
             ==  y % n + 0
             ==  y % n
```

3) you can try adding some `const` to `auto` variables.

So you can try with

```
template <int N, int M>
constexpr auto foo ()
{
    std::array<std::array<int, N>, M> a = {};

    for(int m = 1; m < M; m++)
    {
        auto const m42 = m ^ 42;
        auto const m420 = m % 420;

        for(int n = 1; n < N; n++)
        {
            // For exposition only
            auto const x = m42 + (n << 3) - m;
            auto const y = (n ^ 420) + m420;
            a[m][n] = (a[x % m][y % n] + (x ^ y)) % 0xFACADE;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

If this works, you can try working over `x % m`, splitting components of `x` that arn't dependent from `n` (`m42 - m`) and the dependent one (`n << 3`), so you can compute part of `x % m` outside the inner loop.

Comment: `(x + m) % m` prevents negative values. Hoisting is among one of the things optimizers do. I'm pretty sure `const` is completely ignored here for purposes of optimizing, considering their SSA form is identical. Finally these are all applicable for code for run-time, but due to the way `constexpr` functions work and the abysmal speed at which they operate, I suspect they are quite different and these advice doesn't necessarily translate over.

Comment: As anecdotal evidence, I can't perceive any difference between this version and the original.

Comment: @PasserBy - "prevents negative values" - Ops; I didn't think about it. But... so you should write `x = m42 + (n << 3))` and, after, (`(x - m) ^ y`); `y` can't be negative, if I'm not wrong.